# How to send zip attachment in ruby for SOAP webservice

Tags: ruby, soap

I wanted to consume SOAP web service in Ruby.
        This SOAP web service has attachment which expects zip file to be sent. How to send zip attachment through ruby

```
I use Savon gem to connect to SOAP Webservice
```

Comment: Please tell us, what have you tried so far and where did you encounter ploblem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there is not support of attachments in `savon`.

Try using `savon-multipart`, or `soap4r`.

Check out this question [How do I use Ruby's SOAP::Attachment class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329802/how-do-i-use-rubys-soapattachment-class)